# A question on $\omega_2$

Tags: general-topology, ordinals

Let $X=\omega_2$ and $\tau=\{U\subset X: |X\setminus U|<\omega_2\}$ is the topology on $X$. Then could the space $X$  be star countable?

If it is not, what about the space $Z=\omega_1$ and $\tau'=\{U\subset X: |X\setminus U|<\omega_1\}$?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both spaces are star countable.

More generally, let $\kappa$ be an infinite regular cardinal, let $\mathscr{F}=\{F\subseteq\kappa:|F|<\kappa\}$, and let $$\tau=\{U\subseteq\kappa:\kappa\setminus U\in\mathscr{F}\}\cup\{\varnothing\}\;;$$ then $\tau$ is a star countable topology on $\kappa$.

To see this, let $\mathscr{U}$ be an open cover of $\kappa$. Fix $V\in\mathscr{U}$. For each $\xi\in\kappa\setminus V$ there is a $V_\xi\in\mathscr{U}$ such that $\xi\in V_\xi$. Let $\mathscr{V}=\{V\}\cup\{V_\xi:\xi\in\kappa\setminus V\}\subseteq\mathscr{U}$; clearly $\mathscr{V}$ covers $\kappa$. Let $F=\bigcup_{W\in\mathscr{V}}(\kappa\setminus W)$; then $F$ is the union of fewer than $\kappa$ sets, each of cardinality less than $\kappa$, so $|F|<\kappa$, and

$$\bigcap\mathscr{V}=\kappa\setminus F\ne\varnothing\;.$$

Thus, $X=\operatorname{St}\big(\{\xi\},\mathscr{V}\big)$ for each $\xi\in\bigcap\mathscr{W}$, and $\kappa$ is not just star countable, but star-$1$, so to speak.

Comment: Brian. Scott. I am looking for an example like that something true in case $\omega_1$ but not for $\omega_2$ Do you know such example? even in topology or analysis or set theory .

Comment: @00GB: It’s a pretty trivial example, but for $\kappa=\omega_1$ this space is Lindelöf, while for $\kappa=\omega_2$ it is not.

Comment: Brian. Scott, by trivial example, do you mean the same OP? or not? I would like to see the detials for that maybe this will help to see the difference between $\omega_2$ and $\omega_1.$ I still do not have good how they differ from each other

Comment: @00GB: I was talking about the spaces in my answer, which for $\kappa\in\{\omega_1,\omega_2\}$ are the OP’s spaces. If $\kappa=\omega_1$, every open cover clearly has a countable subcover. Pick any one element of the cover; it covers all but countably many points, so you need at most countably many more members of the cover to cover the whole space. If $\kappa=\omega_2$, however, let $U=\omega_2\setminus\omega_1$, and for each $\xi\in\omega_1$ let $U_\xi=U\cup\{\xi\}$; then $\{U_\xi:\xi<\omega_1\}$ is an open cover of $\omega_2$ with no countable subcover.

Comment: Brian. Scott, Thank your answer is helpful as usual. I have one more question. . I am very sure you have better understanding for cardinals. Usually mathematicians have a big picture about the concepts. what kind of picture do you have in your mind when you see $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$

Comment: @00GB: I’m actually rather non-visual and don’t have much of a picture of either. To the extent that I have one at all, it’s much the same for both, the only difference being that in $\omega_1$ all of the limit ordinals are the limits of ordinary sequences, while in $\omega_2$ there is a cofinal set of limit ordinals that are not limits of simple sequences but **are** limits of sequences of length $\omega_1$. That’s probably not very helpful, but it really is pretty much how I think of them.